# Ruby on Rails: Polymorphic/Object-agnostic conditions on Trigger setups?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, triggers, polymorphic-associations, observers

*I'm not really sure what concept this problem would go under - would this be considered polymorphic associations?

---

I want to create a system where users can set up triggers so that after a certain event happens, another event happens.

For example, I want the user to be able to define a trigger action as:

"This [Email, Document] must be sent to all users after they [Sign up, read email A, sign document B]."

As you can see within the brackets "[]", the conditions can be tied to various objects and actions. 
My thought was to create a model TriggerCondition and storing columns

```
:object_id, :assigned_to, :activated_when
```

but the object_id(Email, Document) can be different models.

1. Would adding a column :object_type that can be either email or document be the best solution? Or is there a more sophisticated way of designing so that I can pass in an object and it will automatically know what I'm referring to?
2. Regarding the :activated_when condition, I'm completely unsure how I would store and check for condition. Would I be able to use a syntax similar to "Email#marked_as_read(A)?"

I'm trying to use Rails Observers to trigger the action
http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/classes/ActiveRecord/Observer.html

Answer (score 0):

Rails is built to handle [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) just like this.

Comment: Right I've been looking at polymorphic associations, but I'm not sure how I would apply that here. Would TriggerCondition have both email and document as polymorphic children? And how would I store/check the :activated_when conditions?

Comment: Your TriggerCondition model would `belongs_to triggerable`. Your email and document would both then `has_many` TriggerConditions, as `triggerable `. This way, Rails now knows which model type a TriggerCondition is associated to.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! How would you handle the :activated_when trigger condition?